# Do the Add methods of the DbSet result in an immediate query to a database in EF?

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, api, entity-framework-core

Do the Add methods of the DbSet result in an immediate query to a database in EF?

I am just curious whether or not the `Add<TEntity>(TEntity entity)`, `AddRange<TEntity>(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)` and the `AddRange<TEntity>(params TEntity[] entities)` will perform the query immediately.

According to [this](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbset/adding-data) article they won`t query a database immediately. That is because in one of the examples in the article we have the following piece of code:

```
context.Authors.Add(author);
context.SaveChanges();
```

But I was not able to find a confirmation of this in documentation. So, could someone, please, confirm my assumption that the DbSet Add method do not query a database until the SaveChanges is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't. The `INSERT` statement(s) will be executed as part of the `SaveChanges` call.

Pre add, all that's here is our `SELECT` from the `ToList()` call...

[image: Pre-add]

After Add...

[image: On Add]

And on `SaveChanges`...

[image: Bingo.]

To monitor behaviour around EF including timing when/what SQL statements are executed I would highly recommend using a profiler against your database, preferably a local database with little "noise" from unrelated queries. This way you can set a breakpoint where you have doubts then watch the profiler for activity on the database. Profiled databases can uncover all kinds of potential performance and behaviour pitfalls when dealing with an ORM.